# T-SQL insert with select and extra column populated by default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to insert into a table using a select and adding a couple of extra columns. The extra columns have default values and one is populated by a sequence by default so not sure why I can't do:

```
insert into ADDRESS_HIST 
    select * from ADDRESS;
```

Getting error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
insert into ADDRESS_HIST 
    select 
        *,
        null as [END_DATE],
        getdate() as [EFFECTIVE_DATE],
        next value for ADDRESS_HIST_ID_SEQ as [ADDRESS_HIST_ID] 
    from 
        ADDRESS;
```

Error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ADDRESS_HIST_ID', table 'ADDRESS_HIST'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I've tested my sequence and its working fine.

Any insight most appreciated.

Edit: I thought that the first example would be possible if the extra columns were either provided a default value or nullable. my mistake.
What is the issue with the second example? I am clearly supplying a value from a sequence for ADDRESS_HIST_ID.

Comment: error msg is very explicit.

Comment: Adding the schemas for the tables would be helpful. And it's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages have already given you the answer.

In the first case, if the number of columns of `ADDRESS_HIST` is different from that of `ADDRESS`, you have to specify the columns like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME 
  (column1, column2, column3,...columnN) VALUES 
  (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

In the second case, obviously you're inserting a null value into a non-nullable column of `ADDRESS_HIST`.

Comment: so the first case is not possible even if default values are supplied by the table definition? and the second case is possible? again, its obvious that I am supplying a value for the column that the error message complains about.

Comment: @rocketboy2000 yes, default value can't help. It doesn't know which column should be given a default value. You'd better explicitly specify the columns, also to make sure the data insert won't mess up in case of a table schema change. Second case, may be fine if the number of columns are matching. It's not preferred though.

Comment: I figured out just what my issue was... one can attempt to qualify extra column names like "as extra_column1" etc but sql server appears to ignore this. column names MUST be in the order in which they appear in the table.